# Can I call interface from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android

I am just asking for knowledge , can we call Interface from one activity to another activity

If it possible then can anyone share code with me?

Comment: What do you mean by call interface from one activity to another activity ?

Comment: Fragments <--> activities, yes. But as only 1 activity is active at a time, it makes less sense to use an interface for activity to activity communication. What kind of data are you wanting to pass between activities?

Comment: "If it possible then can anyone share code with me?"

This is not a Tutorial site. You need to show your code first whatever error you get and what you have done so far. Read the SO documentation.

Comment: i am just asking if it possible .i don't know but if i want to do this and get data from another activity to our activity using interface without using intent , so its not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can't*

**Why?**
Activity object is created by system. We all just call `startActivity()` & work in its lifecycle methods like `onCreate()`, `onStart()` etc.

If you really need it you can use fragment.